# Storage space in SD card

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow

My phone is Samsung galaxy j2 prime, Android 6.0.1.
When I try to move app from internal storage to SD card, it shows 'Not enough storage' even there is 4.6 GB free in my SD card. Anyone please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: temporarily put in a new sd card.

If the problem stops, then the old sd card has a problem.

If the problem still continues with this new sd card also, there may be a problem in Android system. You may try apps which help in moving apps to sd card **without root access**. If they too fail, take your phone to a service centre.